# RegEx: Match string if other string was written before

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `JavaScript` `RegEx` rule to match `url`. When the rule is matching, I convert the string to a link element.

This is my `RegEx` rule:

```
/^(((http(s)?|(ftp(s)?)):\/\/)(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\.\/-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,})+(\:[0-9]{5})?|(mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm;
```

When I start typing for example `https://www.google.com` and hit space at the end, the typed in string matches the `RegEx` rule and my convert logic happens.

But when I type a different string before it like this: `hello world https://www.google.com` and hit space, there is no match. How can I change the `RegEx` rule, so that it also matches the string when other strings are written before it.

Comment: Remove anchors, see https://regex101.com/r/LplryR/1. Or replace with word boundaries, `\b` (but then remove the `\s` at the end), see https://regex101.com/r/LplryR/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome, thanks! Another question: I removed the first anchor `^` but keep the `$` at the end so I can trigger, when the url is finished and stop converting to link and write normal text after the link. Now after removing the first anchor, I have to hit three times spaces to insert a space and continiue writing after the link. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is not related to the current question. No idea what your code looks like and what you are doing. Your regex does not match individual spaces.